# BigQuery: Create monthly buckets from rows using timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to analyse rolling user retention from a list of Orders. The data I have looks like:

```
| order_id | user_id | price | date       |
-------------------------------------------
| 222      | abc     | 100   | 2020-06-02 | 
| 333      | abc     | 140   | 2020-06-12 |
| 444      | abc     | 100   | 2020-07-05 |
| 444      | abc     | 100   | 2020-09-06 |
```

I want to create accumulative totals for price (p) and booking count (c) for each 30 day period from the date of the first user order. I want the data to look something like:

```
| first_order_date | user_id  | 30d_p | 30d_c | 60d_p | 60d_c | 90d_p | 90d_c | 120_p | 120_c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2020-06-02       | 222      | 240   | 2     | 340   | 3     | 340   | 3     | 440   | 4
```

Is this possible using BigQuery?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (different ids):
This should do what you are looking for:

```
WITH orders as (
      SELECT * FROM UNNEST([STRUCT (222 as order_id, "abc" as user_id, 100 as price, DATE("2020-06-02") as date),
                                   (333, "abc", 140, "2020-06-12"),
                                   (444, "cde", 100, "2020-07-05"),
                                   (555, "cde", 100, "2020-09-06")]))
                                   
    ,t2 as (SELECT t1.date, user_id, (SELECT SUM(t2.price) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS _30d_p,
                             (SELECT COUNT(t2.order_id) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS _30d_c,
                             (SELECT SUM(t2.price) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 60 DAY)) AS _60d_p,
                             (SELECT COUNT(t2.order_id) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 60 DAY)) AS _60d_c,
                             (SELECT SUM(t2.price) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)) AS _90d_p,
                             (SELECT COUNT(t2.order_id) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)) AS _90d_c,
                             (SELECT SUM(t2.price) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 120 DAY)) AS _120d_p,
                             (SELECT COUNT(t2.order_id) 
                              FROM orders AS t2 
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.date < DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 120 DAY)) AS _120d_c
    FROM orders t1
    ORDER by t1.order_id)
    
SELECT row.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t2 LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY user_id
)
```

Bear in mind that BQ column names cannot start with numbers.

This will return the first one of each user_id.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because I end up with four rows. I need to pass in the first order date to all queries.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. The first row is the exact same row that you posted as expected result. You can simply add a LIMIT 1 and does it. I don't get it why you said this is not quite working.

Comment: That wouldn't work through if you had multiple userids? Also I want to continue the data beyond 120 days, is there a way to loop the select it instead of copying and pasting?

Comment: Check my last update. This works for different ids. 
Regarding your last question, I don't think so.